# jest + mongoose gives Error Schema with array of arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I'm doing tests with jest and mongoose with the following schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PolygonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Polygon'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [[[Number]]], // Array of arrays of arrays of numbers
    required: true
  }
});

export default PolygonSchema;
```

When running the test with jest i'm getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _schemaType.caster.clone is not a function

      1 | import mongoose from 'mongoose';
      2 | 
    > 3 | const PolygonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        |                       ^
      4 |   type: {
      5 |     type: String,
      6 |     enum: ['Polygon'],

      at Schema.Object.<anonymous>.Schema.path (node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:679:40)
      at Schema.add (node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:444:12)
      at new Schema (node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:121:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/polygon.schema.js:3:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/geofence.model.js:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/services/geofence.service.js:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/services/geofence.test.js:5:1)
```

The code is running well, only with jest I get this error.
I'm also using babel-jest.

Any ideas for a fix? 
Thanks ahead

Comment: What `testEnvironment` have you configured jest for?

Comment: in my jest.config.js file my testEnvironment is node